# How to scale the points on this plot to a different variable?

Tags: r, plot3d

I made a Temperature-Salinity plot and need to scale the size of the points to a different variable. A temperature-salinity plot is a plot that takes the temperature and salinity and finds the density and plots it based on three values. In the example picture, the curved lines represent density.

Here is what a row of my data looks like:

| Temperature | Salinity | pCO2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23.253 | 36.929 | 352.7 |

Heres my code of my plot (this code basically makes an empty graph and you have to manually make each point an object and apply it to the graph):

```
#FORMING GRAPH FRAME:
library(shape)
library(marelac)
library(plot3D)
S.seq <- seq(from = 20, to = 40, length.out = 100)
t.seq <- seq(from = 20, to = 40, length.out = 100)
sig.mat <- outer(S.seq, t.seq, FUN = function(S, t) sw_dens(S = S, t = t) - 1000)
#GRAPH FRAME:
  contour2D(x = S.seq, y = t.seq, z = sig.mat, lwd = 3,
            xlab = 'Salinity', ylab = 'Temperature (°C)',main = 'Surface T-S')
```

Here is an example of making the objects for the graph:

```
t2s = 23.253
S2s = 36.929
```

And then apply those objects to the graph:

```
scatter2D(S2s, t2s, pch=20, col ='darkgreen', cex= 1, add= TRUE, 
          clim = range(sig.mat), colkey = FALSE)
```

Here is an example of a final product with all the points on it:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsH3K.png)

But I need the points to be scaled to the pCO2 value.
Or if you know an easier way to do this type of plot, any feedback is helpful.

Comment: Already tried `cex=pCO2`?

Comment: Would I need to assign pCO2 as an object?

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I am just going to have to find some way to present the scales relative to pCO2 to adequately represent the pCO2 levels without having gigantic dots in the plot.

Comment: Try multiply by a constant `pCO2*.01` or use logarithmic `log(pCO2)`.

Comment: I found 6 jenks natural breaks in the dataset and assigned a size to each natural break. it seemed to get the job done. Thanks so much for the help, you will definitely be in the acknowledgments in my thesis.